# Probrem with LibHaru library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, windows-ce, libharu

I have problem with encountered linking errors :

> Error 112 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
> HPDF_Stream_WriteToStreamWithDeflate referenced in function
> HPDF_Stream_WriteToStream C:\Users\tykab\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Visual
> Studio 2013\Projects\PDF2\PDF2\hpdf_streams.obj   PDF2
>
> Error 111 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
> HPDF_Image_LoadPngImage referenced in function
> LoadPngImageFromStream    C:\Users\tykab\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Visual Studio
> 2013\Projects\PDF2\PDF2\hpdf_doc_png.obj

> Error 113 error LNK1120: 2 unresolved
> externals C:\Users\tykab\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Visual Studio
> 2013\Projects\PDF2\Toradex_CE800\Debug\PDF2.exe   PDF2

I use Visual Studio 2013 for this project.
The source code is written in C programming language, I use C++
Header file of hpdf_stream.h which is related with errors have extern "C" identifier.
I put code of this header below:

```
#ifndef _HPDF_STREAMS_H
#define _HPDF_STREAMS_H

#include "hpdf_list.h"
#include "hpdf_encrypt.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


#define HPDF_STREAM_SIG_BYTES  0x5354524DL

typedef enum _HPDF_StreamType {
    HPDF_STREAM_UNKNOWN = 0,
    HPDF_STREAM_CALLBACK,
    HPDF_STREAM_FILE,
    HPDF_STREAM_MEMORY
} HPDF_StreamType;

#define HPDF_STREAM_FILTER_NONE          0x0000
#define HPDF_STREAM_FILTER_ASCIIHEX      0x0100
#define HPDF_STREAM_FILTER_ASCII85       0x0200
#define HPDF_STREAM_FILTER_FLATE_DECODE  0x0400
#define HPDF_STREAM_FILTER_DCT_DECODE    0x0800
#define HPDF_STREAM_FILTER_CCITT_DECODE  0x1000

typedef enum _HPDF_WhenceMode {
    HPDF_SEEK_SET = 0,
    HPDF_SEEK_CUR,
    HPDF_SEEK_END
} HPDF_WhenceMode;

typedef struct _HPDF_Stream_Rec  *HPDF_Stream;

typedef HPDF_STATUS
(*HPDF_Stream_Write_Func)  (HPDF_Stream      stream,
                            const HPDF_BYTE  *ptr,
                            HPDF_UINT        siz);


typedef HPDF_STATUS
(*HPDF_Stream_Read_Func)  (HPDF_Stream  stream,
                           HPDF_BYTE    *ptr,
                           HPDF_UINT    *siz);


typedef HPDF_STATUS
(*HPDF_Stream_Seek_Func)  (HPDF_Stream      stream,
                           HPDF_INT         pos,
                           HPDF_WhenceMode  mode);


typedef HPDF_INT32
(*HPDF_Stream_Tell_Func)  (HPDF_Stream      stream);


typedef void
(*HPDF_Stream_Free_Func)  (HPDF_Stream  stream);


typedef HPDF_UINT32
(*HPDF_Stream_Size_Func)  (HPDF_Stream  stream);


typedef struct _HPDF_MemStreamAttr_Rec  *HPDF_MemStreamAttr;


typedef struct _HPDF_MemStreamAttr_Rec {
    HPDF_List  buf;
    HPDF_UINT  buf_siz;
    HPDF_UINT  w_pos;
    HPDF_BYTE  *w_ptr;
    HPDF_UINT  r_ptr_idx;
    HPDF_UINT  r_pos;
    HPDF_BYTE  *r_ptr;
} HPDF_MemStreamAttr_Rec;


 typedef struct _HPDF_Stream_Rec {
    HPDF_UINT32               sig_bytes;
    HPDF_StreamType           type;
    HPDF_MMgr                 mmgr;
    HPDF_Error                error;
    HPDF_UINT                 size;
    HPDF_Stream_Write_Func    write_fn;
    HPDF_Stream_Read_Func     read_fn;
    HPDF_Stream_Seek_Func     seek_fn;
    HPDF_Stream_Free_Func     free_fn;
    HPDF_Stream_Tell_Func     tell_fn;
    HPDF_Stream_Size_Func     size_fn;
    void*                     attr;
} HPDF_Stream_Rec;


 int
     main(int argc, char **argv);
__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_Stream
HPDF_MemStream_New  (HPDF_MMgr  mmgr,
                     HPDF_UINT  buf_siz);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_BYTE*
HPDF_MemStream_GetBufPtr  (HPDF_Stream  stream,
                           HPDF_UINT    index,
                           HPDF_UINT    *length);


 HPDF_UINT __cdecl
HPDF_MemStream_GetBufSize(HPDF_Stream  stream);


HPDF_UINT __cdecl
HPDF_MemStream_GetBufCount  (HPDF_Stream  stream);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_MemStream_Rewrite  (HPDF_Stream  stream,
                         HPDF_BYTE    *buf,
                         HPDF_UINT    size);


__declspec(dllimport) void
HPDF_MemStream_FreeData  (HPDF_Stream  stream);


HPDF_STATUS __cdecl
HPDF_Stream_WriteToStream  (HPDF_Stream   src,
                            HPDF_Stream   dst,
                            HPDF_UINT     filter,
                            HPDF_Encrypt  e);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_Stream
HPDF_FileReader_New  (HPDF_MMgr   mmgr,
                      const char  *fname);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_Stream
HPDF_FileWriter_New  (HPDF_MMgr        mmgr,
                      const char  *fname);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_Stream
HPDF_CallbackReader_New  (HPDF_MMgr              mmgr,
                          HPDF_Stream_Read_Func  read_fn,
                          HPDF_Stream_Seek_Func  seek_fn,
                          HPDF_Stream_Tell_Func  tell_fn,
                          HPDF_Stream_Size_Func  size_fn,
                          void*                  data);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_Stream
HPDF_CallbackWriter_New (HPDF_MMgr               mmgr,
                         HPDF_Stream_Write_Func  write_fn,
                         void*                   data);


__declspec(dllimport) void
HPDF_Stream_Free  (HPDF_Stream  stream);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_WriteChar  (HPDF_Stream  stream,
                        char    value);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_WriteStr  (HPDF_Stream      stream,
                       const char  *value);


HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_WriteUChar  (HPDF_Stream  stream,
                         HPDF_BYTE    value);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_WriteInt  (HPDF_Stream  stream,
                       HPDF_INT     value);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_WriteUInt  (HPDF_Stream  stream,
                        HPDF_UINT    value);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_WriteReal  (HPDF_Stream  stream,
                        HPDF_REAL    value);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_Write  (HPDF_Stream      stream,
                    const HPDF_BYTE  *ptr,
                    HPDF_UINT        size);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_Read  (HPDF_Stream  stream,
                   HPDF_BYTE    *ptr,
                   HPDF_UINT    *size);

__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_ReadLn  (HPDF_Stream  stream,
                     char    *s,
                     HPDF_UINT    *size);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_INT32
HPDF_Stream_Tell  (HPDF_Stream  stream);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_Seek  (HPDF_Stream      stream,
                   HPDF_INT         pos,
                   HPDF_WhenceMode  mode);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_BOOL
HPDF_Stream_EOF  (HPDF_Stream  stream);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_UINT32
HPDF_Stream_Size  (HPDF_Stream  stream);

__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_Flush  (HPDF_Stream  stream);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_WriteEscapeName  (HPDF_Stream      stream,
                              const char  *value);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_WriteEscapeText2  (HPDF_Stream    stream,
                               const char    *text,
                               HPDF_UINT      len);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_WriteEscapeText  (HPDF_Stream      stream,
                              const char  *text);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_WriteBinary  (HPDF_Stream      stream,
                          const HPDF_BYTE  *data,
                          HPDF_UINT        len,
                          HPDF_Encrypt     e);


__declspec(dllimport) HPDF_STATUS
HPDF_Stream_Validate  (HPDF_Stream  stream);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif  __cplusplus 

#endif _HPDF_STREAMS_H
```

Below is calling function which causing linking error:

```
    void CPDF2View::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CView::OnInitialUpdate();
    AfxGetMainWnd()->ActivateTopParent();

    HPDF_Doc pdf;
    pdf = HPDF_New(error_handler, NULL);
    HPDF_Page page_1;

    page_1 = HPDF_AddPage(pdf);
    HPDF_SaveToFile(pdf, "test.pdf");

    Invalidate(TRUE);
}
```

I used /VERBOSE for diagnosing Linker Output, and I get informaption that hpdflib.lib is unused.
Can sb can me explain what is a problem?

Comment: You need to link the library, too, not only to include the headers. Check out Properties | Linker | Input and add the library there to be linked. Don't forget about the path, too.

Comment: @AdrianRoman I Included

Comment: It was quite a bit of time since I used libharu so I don't recall all the details, but it might be the case that other libraries are needed, too (such as an image lib, for example). Be sure that all of them are included.

Comment: @AdrianRoman zlib and pnglib also are included

Comment: "hpdflib.lib is unused" That's an odd thing. Check out how the library was compiled. If I understand correctly, you edited a library header. That's a big no. Use extern "C" where you include the hpdflib headers in your code and do that for any header you include from that library, not just for some.